# Spring security requests after login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I understand the initial basic authentication used by Spring security but how does spring security 
handle subsequent request to server after user has been authenticated? I mean where does spring looks up to check user credentials and not to ask the user to enter its password after each request to secure resource on server?

As for the classic session id authentication after the server sent session id to browser how spring security interacts with it and not asking for password for each request?

Comment: The authentication, by default, is s tored in the session. That is restored on each request and directly available. Also when using Basic authentication after succesful login each request will include the Basic Authentication header which itself includes the username/password (so  you could also re-authenticate automatically).

Comment: So spring authenticated each incoming request? if I use data base authentication I call data base in each request? doesn't spring cache the Authentication?

Comment: Have you actually **read** my comment. The first sentence -> *The authentication, by default, is s tored in the session. That is restored on each request and directly available.*

Comment: I did read. Thank you. The Authentication object is stored in session but does it mean that each request spring takes the credentials from the Authentication object and check against data in data base (assume I use data base as user store)

Comment: No, as stated it is used as is. You authenticate only once in a stateful environment.